# Microsoft wireless mouse scroll speed too high

Tags: mouse, xorg, arch-linux, scrolling, openbox

I am using arch linux.
I have a new microsoft wireless mouse which scrolls(with the middle scroll wheel)  too fast.
I don't use kde or gnome but openbox and sometimes xmonad. I want to know how I can slow the scrolling down.
I have come across many kde fixes for this, but no general or xorg fix.

PS: I have a dual boot and with windows 8.1, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently this could have something to do with using it along with Windows.

Taken from the Ubuntu Forum you can try:

> Unplug the mouse receiver from the usb and then plug it back in (while running ubuntu). Whamo blamo you're fixed.

[Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1060002)

Might work for you to, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. It worked, but it is somehow not practical to remove and insert the receiver every time I boot the system. Do you know some permanent fix?

Comment: @rangalo | From what I gather booting a Windows OS changes configuration of your wireless device. If you boot into Ubuntu only it won't bother you, but change to Windows will require an unplug. I might mimic your setup and see if I can find a permanent solution for you.

Comment: Thanks. The windows partition is mainly for the family and pay-tv, so cannot really do away with it.

Answer (score 2):

This is known bug with some Microsoft mice. It is not just quick scroll, if you try to turn scroll wheel very slow you can see that scroll has non-linear speed. Moreover bug persists only if you previously boot to MS Windows (and may be in some other cases). You can fix it by:

- [resetmsmice](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resetmsmice/) app
- unplug & plug mouse receiver
- resetmsmice kernel patch (can be found in tar.gz distribution of resetmsmice)
- [fix-ms-mouse-scroll](https://github.com/unsacrificed/fix-ms-mouse-scroll) kernel patch

All of this fixes are struggling with the same problem. fix-ms-mouse-scroll patch supports newer kernels and some new mice (at least Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse) in compare to resetmsmice (on which it is based on).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line in xorg.conf under the "InputDevice " section and "{your device name}" subsection:

```
Option  "VertScrollDelta" "{scrollspeed}"
```

where smaller values result in faster scrolling.

Comment: This didn't help. It didn't change anything in the scroll behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just spreading the words.

Try [resetmsmice](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resetmsmice), which will fix this problem, without having to unplug and replug the mouse receiver.

And there is a [AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/resetmsmice).

Many thanks to the author Paul F Richards, also the [Ubuntu launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/971321)