# Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse scrolls erratically on macOS

Tags: macos, mouse, scrolling

My Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse scrolls erratically while I'm using it it macOS.

If I move the scroll wheel a click at a time, it scrolls at an okay amount. However, if I scroll a few clicks at a time, the mouse scrolls way too fast.

I have scroll speed turned all the way down in System Preferences and I'm still having the issue. What else can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After years of looking for answers, I have finally found a satisfactory solution. It's not ideal, but it works.

**Simply unplug the USB receiver and plug it in again.**

This issue may only affect users who switch between Macs and PCs using the same USB receiver. I have the receiver plugged into a powered USB hub and I use both Macs and PCs with the same hub. It appears that when the receiver is used with a PC, it retains some specific settings from Windows as long as power is maintained ([source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1060002)).

Huge thank you to [Matthew Williams](https://superuser.com/users/292270/matthew-williams) for sharing his solution for Linux [here](https://superuser.com/a/723880/651430). The scroll wheel on my Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic mouse is useable again!

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! This issue was driving me crazy

Comment: I can't believe this worked.  I have my dongle plugged into a dock in a shared office and someone with a PC must have used the desk.  I've been literally scrolling with the arrow keys for the last two weeks and going mad.  

Comment: @JPDuffy Yes, that is exactly what I do also! I think virtual machines or at least bootcamp users using a powered dock would likely be affected. 

So happy it helped! I was pulling my hair out for years before I found a solution, it's great to hear this answer saved you some time!